# MSAL AuthorizationCode flow does not return scope of all permissions at the first attempt using Graph API

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Java MSAL sample web application which uses graph API to fetch user information from the graph endpoint /me

My application is a multi tenant application and users from other organizations can give their consent and the app calls the graph /me and show the result on a web page.

My registered application as many permissions for e.g. User.ReadWrite.All. etc (I am experimenting with permissions)

I am using the AuthorizationCode flow. The scope I give to this flow is `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

Now when a user for different organization logs in for the first time and give consent to the application we get an access token which only has the following scope

```
  "scp": "openid profile email",
```

And because of this when my web application calls the graph's /me endpoint it gets the following exception

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken","message":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileAccessDeniedException' was thrown.","innerError":{"date":"2022-06-28T09:17:56","request-id":"bd2dcead-4de2-4492-a26f-46b98d57080f","client-request-id":"bd2dcead-4de2-4492-a26f-46b98d57080f"}}}
```

Now I restart the web application and therefore clearing the token cache and access tokens.
When the same user now logs in to my web app it won't have to give consent to the app again and my web app gets the access token.

This time the access token has the following scope

```
  "scp": "AdministrativeUnit.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All User.ReadWrite.All profile openid email",
```

Now my web application calls the graph /me successfully and displays the result.

My question is how do I get the scope with all the permissions at the first place?

Comment: Hi @kaushik, Can you please share the query details of the first query request i.e client request id and the timestamp of the response.

Comment: You mean the following?

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=openid profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://192.168.211.134:9123/ms_auth/secure/aad&state=68068e7a-4fb9-44fd-8c2c-4092633483d8&nonce=84ef8131-5d25-42e7-81bf-e9f37af71bc6&prompt=select_account&client_id=7ccd8620-51a9-4e4a-a1ce-c9afade3c540&response_mode=query

Comment: Hi @kaushik, no i mean in the graph explorer in response preview when you run the query you will got those detials ,i.e Client request id and timestamp.